# How to use a index value of a dynamic array (which get filled by a click event) for filtering a new array

Tags: javascript, arrays, filter

I'm working on a filter, which filters a array of nested arrays down to the value of one last index.
This happens in 5 steps. At each step you choose which index value (string) get used to filter the array further.

Example: You have 5 categories, each have 6 themes. Each of these 6 themes has 6 focusses(sub themes). Each focus has 6 questions. Each question has 1 answer. First you pick a categorie. This narrows the arrays down to all arrays with that categorie. Then a theme, which narrows the array down to only the arrays with that theme... etc...

So far I managed to filter down to the right question.
You can find the code here: https://github.com/okestens/vertical-filter.git

To get this work, I hardcoded the string "Deskundigheid" as a condition for the equality operator (===) that get used for the filter.

Example:

```
// FILTER QUESTIONS        // I tried to use state.focus[0] but it does not work      
let unique_questionsA = [.             // now this is hardcoded
  ...new Set(formsA.filter((i) => i[2] === "Deskundigheid").map((i) => i[3])),
];                                          --------------

// FUNCTION
function displayQuestionsA() {
  state.questions = [];
  unique_questionsA.forEach(function (question, index) {
    document.getElementById("question" + index).innerHTML = question;
    state.questions.push(question);
  });


------

// the state object

let state = {
  category: [],
  themes: [],
  focus: [],
  question: [],
  answer: [],
};
```

But. What I want this filter to use is not a hardcoded string (deskundigheid) but the exact string that is visible in the div (coming from a click event which creates this filtered array and get stored in the state object). See image.

[image]

I thought: I need to track these arrays (with an object called 'state', capturing these dynamic arrays). If I then want to filter the right questions, by using the value (string) of the chosen focus (For example 'Deskundigheid', which is visible to the user), I just refer to the corresponding index value (state.focus[0]) of that chosen focus string, coming from the dynamic state object.

But, if I use the index state.focus[0] for the filter which creates the questions array, I get an empty array :(

My thought: Although the empty focus array (inside the state object), which get filled by a click event, eventually is filled with the right strings, the filter for the new array (unique_questionsA), which uses 'state.focus[0]' does not read the filled array as ‘filled’ but as empty.

I have not idea why :(

I hope I'm clear. If so, and you maybe have a clue, I would love to have a chat! Thanks O

Comment: hey, first of in your code `state.questions.push(question);` but your state only has `state.question` not `questions` (plural)

Comment: Thanks for notifying Ivan! I noticed, it still gives an empty array, but, this is definitely good to know 

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The question can be summed up to

> how do I get the text of the element when clicked, in an onclick event
> listener callback function.

Your [focusScript.js](https://github.com/Cheizer66/vertical-filter/blob/main/js/focusScript.js) can be modified to

```js
function displayQuestionsA(e) {
  state.questions = [];
  let unique_questionsA = [...new Set(formsA.filter((i) => i[2] === e.target.innerText).map((i) => i[3]))];

}
document.querySelector(".focus__A").addEventListener("click", displayQuestionsA);
```

Notice the `e.target.innerText` which contains the text inside the element that triggered the event(which you clicked).

Answer (score 0):

if I got you correctly - both map and filter functions can give your callback second parameter - the index.

```
arr.map((n,i)=>{console.log(`[${i}]:${n}`)})
```

Comment: Yes, thanks Yosi. Actually I'm already using the second parameters for the filter, as you can see in the code. How can this furthermore solve the problem?